# F-statistic in two-stage least-squares with many instruments

Tags: econometrics, instrumental-variables

There is this rule of thumb that the first stage F-statistic should be >10 in instrumental variable analysis to rule out weak instruments.

Is this "rule" for one instrument only or also valid if I have many instruments?

Comment: What do you mean by "many"? Are you in a high-dimensional setting?

Comment: @AndreasDzemski as many as 10 or maybe 30

Comment: See this answer: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/184803/241093

Comment: @AlexK so this rule of thumb is also valid for more than one instrument? The answer is only about one instrument.

Comment: The "joint significance" in the first sentence of that answer relates to the general case of more than one instrument.  F-test tests the joint significance of all your instruments, with the null hypothesis that all of them are uncorrelated with your endogenous explanatory variable.

Comment: Is that what you meant http://www.mit.edu/~hull/CIV.pdf ?